# how to send an array as parameter to quartz scheduled job in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net-2.0

i use quartz.net in asp.net mvc for executes some scheduled jobs every 1 minute,
normally you can send some parameters to your job in this code i send two string parameter as key/value to my job

```
IJobDetail SendMatchQuestionJob = JobBuilder.Create<QuestionJob>()

                       .UsingJobData("param1", "value1")
                       .UsingJobData("param2", "value2")
                       .Build();
```

i want to send an array of strings to scheduled job instead of simple string value,have you any idead? or sample?

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use JobDataMap. The UsingJobData() has an overload for JobDataMap.
You could build your JobDataMap something like this:

```
IJobDetail SendMatchQuestionJob = JobBuilder.Create<QuestionJob>().Build();
SendMatchQuestionJob.JobDataMap["testArray"] = new string[]{"item1", "item2"};
```

Later you can fetch it from JobDataMap thru execution context:

```
public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
      JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;

      JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap; 
      string[] testArray = (string[]) dataMap["testArray"];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any valid overloads for `UsingJobData()` method so maybe a viable option would be passing a string with a delimiter like:

```
IJobDetail SendMatchQuestionJob = JobBuilder.Create<QuestionJob>()
                       .UsingJobData("params", "value1;value2;value3")
                       .Build();
```

And just splitting it using `string.Split()` method afterwards.